# How to remove file (not being aware of it's extension) in Qt?

Tags: qt

I've a got file in the following path `"...avatars/icon2.png"`. How can I `remove` file having known only it's `bundle name` e.g. `icon2`, I'm aware of it's path but `not extension`.

Comment: So you want to delete "icon2.*"?

Comment: That's kind of like asking how to remove a file without knowing its name. The best you can do is remove *all* files that begin with `icon2.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `QDir::entryInfoList()` and check entries for name. Then use `QFile::remove()` or `unlink()` to remove the file.